# jsPlumb connection & endpoint styles

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

So I have this function creating start- & endpoints,  but I can't figure out how to auto connect them, let alone save & restore them, using the provided style below.

```
function addEndpoints(id,target,source) {   // adding Endpoints (source/target)

// Setting Source-/Startpoint Style
var sourceEndpoint = {
    endpoint:"Dot",
    isSource:true,
    paintStyle:{strokeStyle:"#00CC00",fillStyle:"transparent",radius:7,lineWidth:3},                
    connector:["Flowchart", {gap:8,cornerRadius:5,alwaysRespectStubs:true}],                                                
    connectorStyle:{lineWidth:4,strokeStyle:"#567F9F",joinstyle:"round",outlineColor:"white",outlineWidth:2},
    hoverPaintStyle:{fillStyle:"#295D89",strokeStyle:"#295D89"},
    connectorHoverStyle:{lineWidth:4,strokeStyle:"#295D89",outlineWidth:2,outlineColor:"white"},
    maxConnections: 2,
    anchor:"BottomCenter"
},      
// Setting Targetpoint Style
targetEndpoint = {
    endpoint: ["Rectangle", {width:13, height:13}],                 
    paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"red",radius:11 },
    hoverPaintStyle:{fillStyle:"#295D89",strokeStyle:"#295D89"},
    maxConnections:-1,
    dropOptions:{ hoverClass:"hover", activeClass:"active" },
    isTarget:true,
    anchor:"TopCenter"
};  

if(target == 1){    // add target connector?

    // Putting Targetpoint on Main
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
        $('#'+id),
        targetEndpoint
    );
}

if(source == 1){ // add source connector?
    // Putting Source-/Startpoint on Main
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
        $('#'+id),
        sourceEndpoint
    );
}
```

Anyone has an idea how to auto connect / save & restore the connections using the styles provided?

Comment: can you create a fiddle to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to connect endpoints :

```
var e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("d1", {
    isSource:true,
});

var e2 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("d2", {
    isTarget:true,
});

var conn = jsPlumb.connect({source:e1, target:e2});
```

Regarding the saving/restoring, save the connections (from/to pairs, not styling) and then while re-creating just use the same set of styles.

https://github.com/nitinsurana/jsPlumb-Persistence/blob/master/jsplumb-persistence-plugin.js This is one means to save/load the jsPlumb.

Comment: **just use the same set of styles.** that was exactly my question; HOW do I do that. I also know how to connect endpoints using the jsPlumb.connect function, even though so far I used something like this `var connection1 = jsPlumb.connect({
   source: elem.pageSourceId,
   target: elem.pageTargetId,
   anchors: ["BottomCenter","TopCenter"],` but that obviously drops the style.

Comment: Also, the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schlumpfpirat/so03ck9s/1/) you asked for. :)